# Lua source code transformation: strip away a function call given its approximate location

Tags: lua

I have a bunch of Lua 5.1 files that have this (or similar) construct inside:

```
...
local alpha, 
      beta
      = FUNCTION "gamma"
      {
        'delta',
        'epsilon'
      }
...
```

*That is, a call to the `FUNCTION` that returns a function that returns some values, that are assigned to some local variables, declared at the spot.*

Exact code may vary somewhat — both in style (say, everything may be on the same line), and in content (say, there can be zero arguments passed to the second function call). But always things start with `local`, and end with two chained function calls.

I've got a line number for `FUNCTION` call. I need to find the end of the last function call in the chain (this particular one; there can be more `FUNCTION` calls somewhere further in the file), and remove all file content upwards from that point.

I.e., before:

```
print("foo") -- 01
local alpha = FUNCTION 'beta' -- 02
{ "gamma" } -- 03
print("bar") -- 04
```

after:

```
 -- 03
print("bar") -- 04
```

Any clues on how to approach this?

---

Update:

To be more clear on why naïve regexp approach wouldn't work, a real life example:

```
local alpha
      = FUNCTION ( -- my line number points here
          FUNCTION 'beta' { 'gamma' } ()
            and 'epsilon'
             or 'zeta'
        )
      {
        'eta'
      } -- should be cut from here and above as a result
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but does `gsub("^.-local.-FUNCTION.-}",""` work for you?

Comment: What about the case when FUNCTION call will have parentheses? Or when it will be split to several lines? Or when I'll have several FUNCTION calls per file, and will need to remove middle one? (I assume that `^` anchors on the beginning of the file?)

Comment: I've updated the question with a real life example to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main idea: search for adjacent tits `()()` !

```
local line_no = 12
local str = [[
print("foo")
local nif_nif
      = FUNCTION (
          FUNCTION 'beta' { 'gamma' } ()
            and 'epsilon'
             or 'zeta'
        )
      {
        'eta'
      }
local nuf_nuf
      = FUNCTION (      -- this is line#12
          FUNCTION 'beta' { 'gamma' } ()
            and 'epsilon'
             or 'zeta'
        )
      {
        'eta'
      }                 -- should be cut from here
local naf_naf
      = FUNCTION (
          FUNCTION 'beta' { 'gamma' } ()
            and 'epsilon'
             or 'zeta'
        )
      {
        'eta'
      }
print("bar")
]]

-- cut all text before target "local" keyword
str = str:gsub('\n','\0',line_no):gsub('^.*(local.-%z)','%1'):gsub('%z','\n')

-- enclose string literals and table constructors into temporary parentheses
str = str:gsub('%b""','(\0%0\0)')
         :gsub("%b''",'(\0%0\0)')
         :gsub("%b{}",'(\0%0\0)')

-- replace text in parentheses with links to it
local n, t = 0, {}
str = str:gsub('%b()', function(s) n=n+1 t[n..'']=s return'<\0'..n..'>' end)

-- search for first chained function call and cut it out
str = str:gsub('^.-<%z%d+>%s*<%z%d+>', '')
repeat
  local ctr
  str, ctr = str:gsub('^%s*<%z%d+>', '')
until ctr == 0

-- replace links with original text
t, str = nil, str:gsub('<%z(%d+)>', t)

-- remove temporary parentheses
str = str:gsub('%(%z', ''):gsub('%z%)', '')

print(str)
```

Output:

```
                 -- should be cut from here
local naf_naf
      = FUNCTION (
          FUNCTION 'beta' { 'gamma' } ()
            and 'epsilon'
             or 'zeta'
        )
      {
        'eta'
      }
print("bar")
```

Comment: Wouldn't work for two `FUNCTION` in a row if you need to cut off only first one. I.e. try repeating whole `local alpha ... }` construct twice.

Comment: Yes, this idea should be elaborated to use line number as input.

Comment: "@AlexanderGladysh - Code updated to work with `line_no` input parameter.